# Python sum values from multiple lists (more than two)

Tags: python, list, zip

Looking for a pythonic way to sum values from multiple lists:
I have got the following list of lists:

```
a = [0,5,2]
b = [2,1,1]
c = [1,1,1]
d = [5,3,4]
my_list = [a,b,c,d]
```

I am looking for the output:

```
[8,10,8]
```

I`ve used:

```
print ([sum(x) for x in zip(*my_list )])
```

but zip only works when I have 2 elements in my_list.
Any idea?

Comment: zip works for any number of elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) works for an arbitrary number of iterables:

```
>>> list(map(sum, zip(*my_list)))
[8, 10, 8]
```

which is, of course, roughly equivalent to *your* comprehension which also works:

```
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*my_list)]
[8, 10, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a nice way of doing this, it is also able to handle very large arrays. First we create the `my_list` as a numpy array as such:

```
import numpy as np
a = [0,5,2]
b = [2,1,1]
c = [1,1,1]
d = [5,3,4]
my_list = np.array([a,b,c,d])
```

To get the sum over the columns, you can do the following

```
np.sum(my_list, axis=0)
```

Alternatively, the sum over the rows can be retrieved by

```
np.sum(my_list, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it a `numpy` array and then sum along axis 0:

```
my_list = numpy.array([a,b,c,d])    
my_list.sum(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
[ 8 10  8]
```